# Как выделить здание на карте Yandex при клике кнопкой мыши на здании?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как выделить здание на карте Yandex при клике кнопкой мыши на здании?
Реализовал как и в песочнице ["Определение адреса клика на карте с помощью обратного геокодирования"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RZkC.jpg) , только вместо появления метки над зданием по которому осуществлен клик, сделал  появление балуна с адресом здания.
Так же необходимо чтобы при этом же клике, кроме появления балуна (или метки как в примере из песочницы), происходило выделение здания другим цветом как на приложенном мной изображении.
Искал в разных источниках, по косвенной информации понял, что а API Карты Yandex этого функционала нет, хоть на самих Картах Yandex реализован похожий функционал с выделением здания другим цветом, при наведении на него курсора мыши.
Вопрос: Возможно ли при помощи JS API Яндекс Карт реализовать выделение здания на карте Yandex при клике кнопкой мыши на здании или как вообще это возможно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во второй версии - нет, поскольку там карта растровая и данных о зданиях просто нет. Возможно, когда-нибудь эта возможность появится в третьей версии, где карта векторная. Но третья версия пока ещё сырая и структура данных не устоялась.

Comment: @ВикторКарев - спасибо за пояснение, значит будем ждать появления такого функционала.